# not able to connect mysql built with dockerfile using MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, mysql-workbench

dockerfile is:

```
  FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=xxx
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.17.0.1


EXPOSE 3306
```

I create an image and it is executed and the output in the console is:

```
Initializing database
2017-06-04T21:45:27.614648Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-06-04T21:45:28.165234Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2017-06-04T21:45:28.239707Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2017-06-04T21:45:28.268303Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 1fda3bc6-496f-11e7-b3b9-0242ac110002.
2017-06-04T21:45:28.277209Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-06-04T21:45:28.278001Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2017-06-04T21:45:30.879290Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:30.879349Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:30.879370Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:30.879385Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:30.879548Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
Database initialized
Initializing certificates
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
......+++
........................................................+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
-----
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...+++
.................................+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
-----
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
....................+++
..................+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
-----
Certificates initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
2017-06-04T21:45:34.509988Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-06-04T21:45:34.510828Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 88 ...
2017-06-04T21:45:34.513894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-06-04T21:45:34.513959Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-06-04T21:45:34.513962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-06-04T21:45:34.513964Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-06-04T21:45:34.513966Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-06-04T21:45:34.513968Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-06-04T21:45:34.514876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-06-04T21:45:34.515104Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-06-04T21:45:34.517544Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-06-04T21:45:34.525700Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-06-04T21:45:34.528014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-06-04T21:45:34.539849Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.562076Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-06-04T21:45:34.562134Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-06-04T21:45:34.678858Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.680707Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.680766Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.682159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 2535558
2017-06-04T21:45:34.682671Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-06-04T21:45:34.683101Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.685166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170604 21:45:34
2017-06-04T21:45:34.696752Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.697436Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.711955Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.712006Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.712021Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.712029Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.713467Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.718411Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-06-04T21:45:34.718587Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-06-04T21:45:34.718607Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
2017-06-04T21:45:34.718614Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-06-04T21:45:34.728015Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2017-06-04T21:45:37.697877Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:37.697939Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:37.698177Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:37.698388Z 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:37.698537Z 5 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

2017-06-04T21:45:37.705631Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2017-06-04T21:45:37.705651Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2017-06-04T21:45:37.705674Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2017-06-04T21:45:37.705677Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-06-04T21:45:37.705714Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706515Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706553Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706560Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706565Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706700Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706755Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706781Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706942Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706974Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.706979Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707008Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707013Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707018Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707040Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707182Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707212Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707218Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707223Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707228Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707407Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707429Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707456Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707607Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707636Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707658Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707663Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707684Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707820Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707850Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707856Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707877Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.707992Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.708006Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-06-04T21:45:37.708201Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-06-04T21:45:37.708420Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-06-04T21:45:37.809135Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-06-04T21:45:37.810270Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170604 21:45:37
2017-06-04T21:45:40.157631Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12139694
2017-06-04T21:45:40.166913Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167059Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167298Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167390Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167503Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167541Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167599Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.167717Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.168032Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-06-04T21:45:40.171056Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete


MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2017-06-04T21:45:40.451048Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-06-04T21:45:40.451891Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 1 ...
2017-06-04T21:45:40.457755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-06-04T21:45:40.457782Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-06-04T21:45:40.457786Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-06-04T21:45:40.457788Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-06-04T21:45:40.457790Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-06-04T21:45:40.457795Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-06-04T21:45:40.458346Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-06-04T21:45:40.458615Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-06-04T21:45:40.460659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-06-04T21:45:40.469391Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-06-04T21:45:40.471616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-06-04T21:45:40.483436Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.498521Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-06-04T21:45:40.498599Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-06-04T21:45:40.577051Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.578116Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.578141Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.578560Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-06-04T21:45:40.628859Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 12139694
2017-06-04T21:45:40.629153Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-06-04T21:45:40.629256Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.633930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170604 21:45:40
2017-06-04T21:45:40.634507Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.634772Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.636787Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-06-04T21:45:40.636867Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.636871Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-06-04T21:45:40.636948Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.647855Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.647964Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.648018Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.648026Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.651259Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.655887Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-06-04T21:45:40.656165Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-06-04T21:45:40.656176Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
2017-06-04T21:45:40.656178Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-06-04T21:45:40.664203Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-06-04T21:48:18.537406Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried to connect to DB using root user and diff host as localhost,{ContainerID}, 0.0.0.0, 8.8.8.8, 172.17.0.1, 172.17.0.2 and no luck. 
Could anyone help me out why I can't connect to the DB, please?

everything is running locally. so Mysql Db is running in a container and MySQLWorkbench tool is intalled in my laptop and when I setup MySQLWorkbench to connect to Mysql within container I am getting an error message: 
You connection attempt to failed for user root from your host to server at 172.17.0.1:3306.
Can't connect to MySQL server on 172.17.0.1 (10060)
Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a `-p 3306:3306` parameter to your `docker run` command. this will map the port to `locahost:3306`

Comment: no luck. I am running the following command:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 trw/mysql`
and same issue, I can't access from outside.